# Awk join to handle empty file

Tags: awk

I have 2 files of below format

```
a.txt
-----
1~a
2~b

b.txt
-----
1~one~A
2~two~B
3~three~C
```

if i run the below awk command, i get the correct output

```
awk -F'~' -v OFS="~" 'NR==FNR{a[$1] = $1; b[$1] = $2; next}{if(a[$1] == $1){$2="Matched"} else {$2="No Match"}}1' a.txt b.txt
```

output

```
1~one~Matched
2~two~Matched
3~three~No Match
```

Problem is when my a.txt is empty. The above command does'nt output anything in that case. How do i update the above awk command so that i get the below output.

```
1~one~No Match
2~two~No Match
3~three~No Match
```

Comment: Do you use `GNU awk` or some other implementation?

Comment: How do i check?

Comment: `awk --version` ... also, do you want to compare only first column?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7. Yes, the fist column in the key in both the files in my case. Then there are conditions to update the fields in the output based on some conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following once, written and tested in GNU `awk 5.0.1`. Tested with both `a.txt` empty OR non-empty scenarios and it worked fine. Simply changing `FNR==NR` condition(which will be true for first Input_file always) to `ARGIND==1` so in case first file is empty then it will directly go to if/else statements and will print no match found statements there.

```
awk -F'~' -v OFS="~" 'ARGIND==1{a[$1] = $1; b[$1] = $2; next} {if(a[$1] == $1){$2="Matched"} else {$2="No Match"}}1' a.txt b.txt
```

***Detailed explanation of code's working:***

If we see man awk we get `ARGIND      The index in ARGV of the current file being processed.` it will basically give you index number of passed arguments/files so for first file it will be 1, that's why if first file is empty(a.txt) then block of if/else conditions coming after it will be executed, because in FNR==NR condition was never getting satisfied(because of NULL value of FNR since file is empty so no line number for it) and statements inside it were never getting executed, hence no results with your command.

Comment: It works. What is the difference between NR==FRN and ARGIND==1 may i check?

Comment: @asb, If we see `man awk` we get `ARGIND      The index in ARGV of the current file being processed.` it will basically give you index number of passed arguments/files so for first file it will be 1, that's why if first file is empty(`a.txt`) then block of if/else conditions coming after it will be executed, because in `FNR==NR` condition was never getting satisfied(because of NULL value of `FNR` since file is empty so no line number for it) and statements inside it were never getting executed, hence no results with your command.

Comment: @asb FWIW ARGIND is gawk-specific but in a POSIX awk you can use `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` instead of `ARGIND==1` to get the same result assuming you aren't reading the same file multiple times. If you are then you can do `awk '!f{foo}...' file1 f=1 file2`

Answer (score 3):

See if `ARGIND` is supported in `GNU awk 3.1.7` version:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~"} ARGIND==1{a[$1]; next}
       {$3 = ($1 in a) ? "Matched" : "No Match"} 1' f1 f2
1~one~Matched
2~two~Matched
3~three~No Match

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~"} ARGIND==1{a[$1]; next}
       {$3 = ($1 in a) ? "Matched" : "No Match"} 1' /dev/null f2
1~one~No Match
2~two~No Match
3~three~No Match
```

Since you need to compare only first field, single array with field content as the key is enough. No need to save value, you can check for the presence of a key using `in`.

Alternate solution that should work with any `awk`, based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/618158/109046):

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~"} !second_file{a[$1]; next}
     {$3 = ($1 in a) ? "Matched" : "No Match"} 1' f1 second_file=1 f2
```

Here, `second_file` is a flag that is set between the two files.

Comment: Right, or `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` if you aren't reading the first file multiple times.